# How can I make a list plot with bars?

Tags: plotting, histograms, charts

Can anyone help me please? I don't want a Histogram; I don't want a BarChart, not even a ListPlot with drop down lines. I want a list plot with drop down columns/bars: please see the link.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is basically a histogram but of a different kind. The data structure contains two variables for example in the above figure it was energy and standard deviation. And the frequency distribution was done based on two cut-offs {0.5,2.0} and finally it was plotted along the energy axis. Therefore, it contains overlapping bars/columns. A projection of a 3D histogram in two dimensions.

Comment: Please provide some data to work on :)

Comment: @Kuba http://blogs.citypages.com/ctg/lt%20cmdr%20data.jpg

Comment: @belisarius can't argue, it's something :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why not just assemble the chart from rectangles?

```
data = {{-6.65, 55}, {-6.45, 15}, {-6.27, 10}, {-6, 5}, {-5.85, 3}, 
 {-6.46, 6}, {-6.25, 3}, {-6.17, 2}};

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black}], RGBColor[0.3, 0.4, 0.4], 
  Rectangle[{#1 - 0.05, 0}, {#1 + 0.05, #2}] & @@@ data},
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 0.7, FrameLabel -> {"Binding Energy", "Cluster Frequency"}]
```

[image]

Comment: By falling back to create your own graphics, you loose all the layout/styling/annotation options of either `BarChart` or `Histogram`. `BarChart` however cannot overlay multiple datasets transparently as `Histogram` does (at least not directly). `Histogram` on the other hand cannot work with already computed bin list data. `DiscretePlot` does not (directly) work on list data. It seems like that a trivial method to overlay multiple datasets as bars does not exist as of 2018.

Answer (score 11):

### BarChart

Although OP says ***"I don't want a BarChart"***, the requirements of *list plot with drop down columns/bars* (*overlapping bars/columns*)  can be achieved using `BarChart` with a simple `ChartElementFunction` that produces the desired rectangles for each data point:

```
ClearAll[ceF]
ceF[w_: .1, df_:"Rectangle"] := ChartElementData[df][{#3[[1]] + {-w, w}/2, #[[2]]}, ##2]&
```

**Examples:**

Using @SimonWoods' example data and options:

```
data = {{-6.65, 55}, {-6.45, 15}, {-6.27, 10}, {-6, 5}, {-5.85, 3}, 
 {-6.46, 6}, {-6.25, 3}, {-6.17, 2}};
```

Pre-rocess `data` to use bin centers as metadata for bin heights:

```
barchartdata = Rule @@@ (Reverse /@ data);
minmax = Through[{Min, Max}@data[[All, 1]]];

w = .1;
BarChart[barchartdata, ChartElementFunction -> ceF[w], 
   ChartBaseStyle -> Opacity[.8], ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",  
   PlotRange -> {minmax + {-w, w}, All}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 0.7, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ 
  {"Binding Energy", "Cluster Frequency"})] /. Line[__] :> Sequence[]
```

[image]

Using `w = .05`:

[image]

Using a different built-in `ChartElementFunction` as input, i.e., with `ChartElementFunction -> ceF[w, "FadingRectangle"]`:

[image]

### DiscretePlot

Define a simple function using `data` and plot it using `DiscretePlot` with your desired setting for the option `ExtentSize` to control bar widths.

```
ClearAll[dF]
Table[dF[d[[1]]] = d[[2]], {d, data}];
```

Examples:

```
w = .1;
DiscretePlot[dF[i], {i, data[[All, 1]]}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {minmax + {-w, w}, {0, 60}}, 
 ExtentSize -> w, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[Gray], Opacity[.3]],
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0], AspectRatio -> 0.7, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ {"Binding Energy", "Cluster Frequency"})]
```

[image]

Use `w = .05` to get

[image]

### ListPlot

You can also post-process `ListPlot` output to change `Point`s into `Rectangle`s.

```
ClearAll[pntToRect]
pntToRect[w_: .1] := # /. Point -> (Rectangle[{#1 - w/2, 0}, {#1 + w/2, #2}] & @@@ # &)&
```

**Example:**

```
pntToRect[]@
 ListPlot[List /@ data, PlotStyle -> "Pastel", BaseStyle -> EdgeForm[Gray], 
  PlotRange -> {minmax + {-.1, .1}, {0, 60}}, Frame -> True, 
  Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.7, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16, "Panel"] & /@ {"Binding Energy", "Cluster Frequency"})]
```

[image]

Comment: I think `ceF` should be `ceFunc`? Also, the `DiscretePlot` example doesn't seem to work properly at least in _v12.3.1_.

Comment: Thank you @xzczd for catching the errors.  Both are fixed now.